# Exclusion in find

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using the bash following script to look for string in files:

```
find $1 -name "$2" -exec grep -Hn "$3" {} \;
```

Sometimes this script failed on

```
grep: /proc/sysrq-trigger: Input/Output error
```

In order to solve this I first think to exclude this file from the find result. is it a good idea and if yes how can I do that ? Is there any other solution to avoid my script failing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude all `/proc` directory in find like this:

```
find $1 -path /proc -prune -o -name "$2" -print -exec grep -Hn "$3" {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that `--exclude-dir` is designed to work when grep it's self is doing the filesystem recursion (`grep -r`) not when grep is used with find.  Why don't you combine it with xargs instead and filter out the proc entries with another grep?

```
find $1 -name "$2" | grep -v '/proc' | xargs grep -Hn "$3" {} \;
```